# An unhandled exception of type 'system.formatexception' occurred in mscorlib.dll in update button

Tags: mysql, vb.net

When i Hit my Update button i get An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. I'm suppose to update my database values. Only mobile number is the value that you can update.

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgSVO.jpg)

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System
Imports System.Data

Public Class AddStudent
Dim connString As String = "server=localhost;userid=jared;password=jared;database=database;persistsecurityinfo=True"
Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
Dim student As New DataTable()


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim iReturn As Boolean
    Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connString)
        Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO students (StudentNumber, Firstname, Surname, Number) values (@sNumber,@sName,@sLname,@sNum)"
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sNumber", TextBox1sn.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sName", TextBox1name.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sLname", TextBox2su.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sNum", TextBox3num.Text)

            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                iReturn = True
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                iReturn = False



            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function InsertStud() As Boolean
    Dim iReturn As Boolean
    Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connString)
        Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            With sqlCommand

                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO students (StudentNumber, Firstname, Surname, Number) values (@sNumber,@sName,@sLname,@sNum)"
                .Connection = SQLConnection
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sNumber", TextBox1sn.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sName", TextBox1name.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sLname", TextBox2su.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sNum", TextBox3num.Text)


            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                iReturn = True
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                iReturn = False


            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Return iReturn
End Function

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click



    Dim iReturn As Boolean
    Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connString)
        Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = "UPDATE students SET StudentNumber = @sNumber, " & TextBox1sn.Text &
                   "`Name`= @sName, Surname=@sLname, Number= @sNum, " & _
                   "College= @sCollege, Course= " & _
                   ("Where StudentNumber = @oldNumber")
                .Connection = SQLConnection
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1sn.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@sName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1name.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@sLname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2su.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@sNum", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3num.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1sn.Text


            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                iReturn = True
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                iReturn = False



            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Dont concat SQL use a parameter for your WHERE clause like you did for the others; `Name` is a reserved word, so you will have to escape that.  Otherwise, tell us where the error happens.  Is Year a numeric type in the Db?

Comment: If `StudentNumber` is an AutoIncrement ID, you probably do not want to update that.  Remove that part from the SQL, and use `@sNumber` for the WHERE clause.  And if it *is* an AI ID, it would not be text/char/string type

Comment: @Plutonix Hello. StudentNumber is NOT an AutoIncrement ID. it is random numbers to be inputed. The error happens on sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your error is the AddWithValue called on the first 4 parameters. The AddWithValue second parameter is the value that you want to assign to the parameter, not its type. 
Using the type as second parameter means that AddWithValue creates a parameter of type integer and when you assign the string to the Value property you get the exception

You should change everything to use the verbose, but more safe Add

```
With sqlCommand
    .CommandText = "UPDATE students SET StudentNumber = @sNumber, " & _ 
                   "`Name`= @sName, Surname=@sLname, Number= @sNum, " & _
                   "College= @sCollege, Course= @sCourse, Year = @sYr " & _
                   "Where StudentNumber = @oldNumber")
    .Connection = SQLConnection

    .Parameters.Add("@sNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1sn.Text
    .Parameters.Add("@sName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1name.Text
    .Parameters.Add("@sLname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2su.Text
    .Parameters.Add("@sNum", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3num.Text
    .Parameters.Add("@sCollege", ???).Value = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    .Parameters.Add("@sCourse", ???).Value = ComboBox2.SelectedItem
    .Parameters.Add("@sYr", ???).Value = ComboBox3.SelectedItem
    .Parameters.Add("@oldNumber, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ???
```

Of course someone has already told you that you need to use parameter for every part of your query, (also the WHERE needs a parameter)

Also notice that I have changed the enum passed to the Add method to use the specific one for MySql. SqlDbType is the generic enum used for the base classes and I am not sure if it has the same values of the MySql one, better use the matching ones then.

Finally the last three parameters use the same approach but I don't know what is the intended MySqlDbType and if you need to convert the SelectedItem property of the combo to the appropriate datatype

**EDIT**
There is also the problem of `Name` being a reserved keyword, put it between backticks and it is not clear what are you trying to update. You use the `Number` in your WHERE condition. There is no need to update the `Number` on the same record with the value of the textbox used also for the search. Instead, if you are trying to change the `Number` field with a new value then you need to use the original value in the WHERE condition.

Comment: that looked funny, but I couldnt put my finger on what was wrong

Comment: @Steve I tried the codes you posted. But still the error is there.

Comment: So let's check one by one your fields. What are their datatype on the database table. Do we pass the correct parameter type for each one? Could you add the datatype of your columns?

Comment: @Steve All of the Datatypes on my database are VarChar.

Comment: So, every parameter should get a string value. If your comboboxes are filled with a datasource (instead of a list of string) then you need to extract the string from the SelectedItem property. Add a ToString() to each SelectedItem and check the results

Comment: Yes. Student Number, FirstName, Lastname cannot be updated. Only Number College Course Year.

Comment: My Comboboxes are still empty. I am still figuring out how to add data bound items. @Steve how can i send you a private message? I really need your help.

Comment: Just try to solve one problem now. Remove the three comboboxes and check if you can save. Then ask a new question with the comboboxes problem

Comment: @Steve i removed all the comboboxes but still cant update my database. I posted all my codes and the error message above